# Two nonlinearly coupled sets of linear inequalities?

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, nonlinear-system, polytopes, geometric-programming

Let $x_{1},...,x_{N}$ and $y_{1},...,y_{N}$ be scalar-values variables. Now assume that I have two sets of linear inequalities inequalities:

$$c_{i,1}x_{1} + \dots + c_{i,N}x_{N} \leq a_{i} \quad i=1,\dots,M \tag{1} $$
$$c_{j,1}y_{1} + \dots + c_{j,N}y_{N} \leq b_{j} \quad j=1,\dots,K \tag{2}$$

where $N,M,K\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$, and all the $a$, $b$, and $c$ are known.

**Goal**: I want to find the vertices of the resulting feasible region.

**Catch**: The $x_n$ and $y_n$ for $n=1,\dots,N$ are not independent, but in fact coupled nonlinearly as $y_n = \log x_n$.

Does this problem have a solution? Do you know of a method that may be able to find the vertices of the resulting feasible region?